# How can I override variables in the maven-publish publishing/publications closure?

Tags: gradle, maven-publish

My project structure is

```
root
|-- build.gradle
|-- gradle.properties
|-- settings.gradle
|-- module1
    |-- build.gradle.kts
    |-- src
        |-- main
            |-- java
            |-- kotlin
            |-- resources
        |-- test
            |-- kotlin
            |-- resources
```

I am relatively new to Gradle, and I have the following in my build.gradle

```
subprojects {
    . . .
    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                from components.java
                versionMapping {
                    usage('java-api') {
                        fromResolutionOf('runtimeClasspath')
                    }
                    usage('java-runtime') {
                        fromResolutionResult()
                    }
                }
                afterEvaluate {
                    pom {
                        name = "pom name"
                        description = "pom description"
                        licenses {
                            license {
                                name = licenseName
                                comments = licenseText
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which mostly does what I want, in particular, `licenseName` and `licenseText` are variables I pick up from elsewhere. However, I want to replace `"pom name"` and `"pom description"` with context dependent values from elsewhere in this file, or a lower-level file in a subproject. Gradle seems to poo-poo all my efforts to do this... For example, in module1/build.gradle.kts I want to be able to say

```
val artifactId = project.name
val pomName = "Crypto Common"
val pomDescription = "Libraries common to other Crypto modules."
```

and in build.gradle replace

```
name = "pom name"
description = "pom description"
```

with

```
name = pomName
description = pomDescription
```

It's interesting that in build.gradle I can refer to `artifactId` but not to `pomName` or `pomDescription`

**Is it possible to do this, and if so, how?**

For example, in the `project('module1') { ... }` closure, or in the `build.gradle` or `build.gradle.kts` file one level down in the sub-project/sub-module directory.

Also, is it possible to have a gradle.properties file in sub-modules, or can it only exist in the project root directory?

Comment: Could you post your directory structure using `tree` or similar. And could you also update your snippet of what you are trying to achieve, specifically what you want `pom.name` and `pom.description` to be/from where.

Comment: Does that help?